# Encapsulation, calculate radius, diameter, area.

Tags: java, encapsulation

I have a data structures assignment and I was able to compile my first code but I don't understand how to access the information. Here is the instructions. (sorry they're long)

Create a class named Circle with field names radius, diameter, and area. Include a constructor that sets the radius to 1 and calculates the other two values. Include methods named setRadius() and getRadius(). The setRadius() method not only sets the radius, but calculates the other two values (as you know, the diameter of a circle is twice the radius, the area of a circle is pi multiplied by the square of the radius). Save class as Circle.java.
Create a class named TestCircle whose main method() declares several Circle objects. Using setRadius() method, assign one circle a small radius value (code a user input making use of Scanner of JOptionPane), and assign another a larger radius value (to be an input by a user as well). Do not assign a value to the radius of the third circle; instead retain the value assigned at object construction. Display all the values for three Circle objects. Save the class as TestCircle.java.

And heres my first class

```
public class Circle {

public int radius = 1;
public double diameter;
public double area;

//Constructor for circle class
public double Circle(int First){
 return radius;
}

//Start set and get for radius
 private double setRadius(int r){
    return radius = 5;
 }

 private double getRadius(){
  return radius;
 }

 //Start set and get for diameter
 public double setDiamter(double d){
    return diameter = 7;
 }
 public double getDiamter(){
  return radius * diameter;
 }

 //Start set and get for diameter
 public double setArea(double a){
    return area;
 }
 public double getArea(){
    return area * Math.PI * 2;
 }
 }
```

And my test code that should call all the first calculation...I can't get the first calculation to work so i'm asking for some help in how to do this.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class TestCircle {

 public static void main(String[] arges) {

 TestCircle C1 = new TestCircle();
  Scanner FirstNum = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Enter a number between 1 and 10 to calculate the diamater");
  First = inputDevice.nextInt; //here is where i thought i could call the First method from the other document. but i'm wrong
  }
  }
```

Comment: your constructor is incorrect. Constructor should not have a return type.

Comment: @Blindy, I don't need those?

Comment: @lacraig2, second thread in a row where you'd have been better off not replying. He has a separate diameter field from the radius field, and he's setting them independently. I probably shouldn't explain it to you though, you really don't know what a circle looks like.

Answer (score 0):

You did not write any method called "First" . You can NOT  call something that is not exist.So firstly; 
 1)Write a method called "First " 
 2)  First = inputDevice.nextInt;    swap this code with this one  , First = FirstNum.nextInt;  scanner has written wrong .

Comment: Can't I call a method from the first document that doesn't have a main method? Encapsulation? I already caught the wrong scanner part. Did you read the instructions to my assignment?

Comment: you can call method that doesn't have a main method,and what is "First " ?

Comment: i don't know anymore. i'm sick and i don't feel like doing this i'm done with it .